# What is the signification of docker run's mount options (type, source, target)?

Tags: docker

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 \
    --mount type=bind,source=$(pwd)/models/mnist,target=/models/mnist \
    -e MODEL_NAME=mnist \
    -t tensorflow/serving &
```

What does parameters `--mount`, `type`, `source`, `target` and symbol `&` mean or work in docker?

I have run commands `docker --help` and `docker run --help`, but still confused with these commands above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to read [the docs related to bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount) to understand `--mount` option with `type=bind` parameter.

In your example, the `mount` option just shares a local directory between your host (`$(pwd)/models/mnist`) and your container (in path `/models/mnist`). That means that all files located on your host in `$(pwd)/models/mnist` will be available from the container in `/models/mnist`.

`&` has nothing to do with Docker, it just [launches your command in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line). You can use docker's `-d` (daemon) option to get same behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I find lots thing in these websites.

Answer (score 4):

With Docker, the most common types of storage that is mounted into containers are the following three (taken from [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#choose-the-right-type-of-mount)):

**Volumes** are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker (`/var/lib/docker/volumes/` on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem. Volumes are the best way to persist data in Docker.

**Bind mounts** may be stored anywhere on the host system. They may even be important system files or directories. Non-Docker processes on the Docker host or a Docker container can modify them at any time.

**tmpfs mounts** are stored in the host system’s memory only, and are never written to the host system’s filesystem.

So with `--mount` you can setup relevant options for those storage types in a very convenient way: 
The `type` field can be one of the 3 types mentioned above. 
The `source` is the mount point location in the *host file system*
(For named volumes, this is the name of the volume, for anonymous volumes, this field is omitted).
The `target` is the mount point location *inside the container*.

---

Please notice that you'll see many examples using the `-v` or `--volume` flags in `docker run`. This was the official way until Docker `17.06`.

(IMHO, use the `--mount` option, it can save you some debugging time, for example it will throw an error if you're trying to mount a directory which doesn't exists, this as opposed to to `--volume` which will create it).

---

The `&` symbol doesn't relate to Docker, it's just for running your command as a daemon in background.